# Excel is has been spinning for over 12 hours. How do I avoid losing data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, freeze

I was trying to edit a macro in the VBA editor. I clicked save and Excel has been "saving" the macro for over 12 hours now. My CPU is running at about 12% and memory usage is around 20%. If I close excel with the task manager I will permanently lose spreadsheet data. What are my options to avoid losing spreadsheet data?

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the file? I'd guess it is locked buy you could try

Comment: if by duplicate you mean copy paste the file yes I can do that , but it won't include the new data I just added  because the file isn't saved.

Comment: Sorry. You may find Excel can auto recover but I don't know how to test that in advance (to preview what state it is in)

Comment: You could open another instance of excel, click open, recent worksheets and then click on recover u saved worksheets

Comment: Almost 48 hours of spinning now. When I try to open another instance of excel it says 1B81C600 is locked for editing. Anyone know where I can find this file 1B81C600?

Answer (score 0):

Excel should not be blocked while the VBA editor is active.

Click on the spreadsheet, save it and close Excel.

If Excel hangs during closing *but after the data is saved*, you may then kill it and
also the VBA editor. The VBA might then be lost.

If the spreadsheet is also blocked and cannot be saved, then you have the question
of whether force-killing Excel via the Task Manager will lose any data.
This is you decision, that I cannot make for you.

Comment: I cannot click on the spreadsheet this visual basic editor has completely locked up excel. is there a way to close the visual basic editor without closing  excel? I don't care about the macro. it is the spreadsheet data that will be lost permanently if its not saved. my cpu is doing something it's ticking away at 12%.

Comment: @Eric - Sounds like you are out of luck

Comment: @Eric: The above comment is right - both the spreadsheet and the VBA editor are handled by the same instance of `excel.exe`. You will need to take your chances.